# Reading time from CSV file in R

Tags: r, date, csv, time

I want to read a CSV file separated by ";" which contains four columns, such as:

```
16/12/2006;17:24:00;0;1
16/12/2006;17:25:00;2;3
16/12/2006;17:26:00;4;5
```

but I want a dataframe with 3 columns rather than 4 (that is, merge the date and hour of the two first columns into a single one).

So far, I have come up with this portion of code inspired by [Specify custom Date format for colClasses argument in read.table/read.csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13022299/specify-date-format-for-colclasses-argument-in-read-table-read-csv) to read the data. Then, I'd merge the two columns somehow.

```
setClass("myDate")
setAs("character","myDate", function(from) as.Date(from, format="%d/%m/%Y") )
setClass("myTime")
setAs("character","myTime", function(from) as.Date(from, format="%H:%M:%S") )

data <- read.table(file = "file.csv", header = FALSE, sep = ";", colClasses =  c("myDate", "myTime", "numeric", "numeric"))
```

However, the resulting data frame does have a column V2 in which the hour is not properly read.

```
          V1         V2 V3 V4
1 2006-12-16 2016-03-04  0  1
2 2006-12-16 2016-03-04  2  3
3 2006-12-16 2016-03-04  4  5
```

Is the myTime class badly defined? If so, how should I change it?

Comment: Did you try as.POSIXlt instead of as.Date? Because you are reading times not dates here.... Plus, IMO I'd read it in raw and then paste them together and then run POSIX... like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35624659/how-to-find-the-difference-of-time-time-taken-to-process-a-file-in-r/35625097#35625097

Comment: Thank you for sharing the link, it was very helpful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there a particular reason why you want to do this during the import, and not after? It seems much easier to import the 4 columns, merge the date and time together using `paste`, and then use the lubridate package and its `dmy_hms` function to convert to proper date-time:

```
require(lubridate)
data <- read.table(file = "file.csv", header = FALSE, sep = ";")
data$date_time <- paste(data$V1, data$V2)
data$date_time <- dmy_hms(data$date_time)
data[1:2] <- list(NULL)
```